# Can an array length constant be defined for a library in another project?

Tags: rust

I have a library that has a statically-sized array in a struct:

```
const SIZE: usize = 32;

pub struct MyStruct {
    ints: [u32; SIZE]
}
```

Can I define the constant `SIZE` somewhere else? More specifically, can I somehow define it in the executable project that uses this library so that it can be tuned to the needs of that project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At time of writing this is not possible. It requires a [const generic](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2000-const-generics.md) argument:

```
pub struct MyStruct<const SIZE: usize> {
    ints: [u32; SIZE]
}
```

But this is not implemented yet. We expect to land this feature in late 2018.